# Where does the term "sex kick" come from?

Tags: terminology, super-smash-bros-series

According to the [SmashWiki](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Sex_kick), a sex kick is an aerial attack in which a foot or arm remains extended for a few moments after the initial thrust. The origin is claimed as:

> The term was coined by smasher Matt Deezie as a sexual innuendo referring to the properties of the attack in the original Super Smash Bros.

What I don't understand is the innuendo. What innuendo is it referring to? The wiki doesn't elaborate further, and my best guess is a crude dick joke, but there's not really much I can think of that relates to the properties of the sex kick.  And then some comments on boards say that Dr. Mario has a reverse sex kick, which is even more confusing.

So what innuendo am I missing? Why is a "sex kick" described as so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/smashbros/comments/328xyo/socan_somebody_explain_to_me_why_its_called_a_sex/) some years back where the community discussed this, and the most-upvoted explanation given was:

> In sex, the thrust is presumably the strongest. That is why a sex kick is stronger during the first few frames.
>
> A reverse sex kick (Dr Mario) is basically just saying that the man with a PHD prefers to go hard after the thrust.

It's a bit weak as far as innuendo goes, but I'd guess at least part of the name choice probably has to do with it being a game that was *incredibly* popular with teenage boys rather than any inherent property of the moves.